# Insert overwrite statement runs much slower in spark-sql than it does in hive-client

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

*spark version: 2.0.0*

*hive version: 2.0.1*

**I find insert overwrite statement running in spark-sql or spark-shell spends much more time than it does in  hive-client (i start it in apache-hive-2.0.1-bin/bin/hive ), where spark costs about ten minutes but hive-client just costs less than 20 seconds.**

These are the steps I took.

Test sql is :

```
INSERT overwrite TABLE login4game partition(pt='mix_en',dt='2016-10-21')
SELECT DISTINCT account_name,
                role_id,
                server,
                '1476979200' AS recdate,
                'mix' AS platform,
                'mix' AS pid,
                'mix' AS dev
FROM tbllog_login
WHERE pt='mix_en'
  AND dt='2016-10-21' ;
```

there are 257128 lines of data in tbllog_login with `partition(pt='mix_en',dt='2016-10-21')`

ps:

I'm sure it must be "insert overwrite" costing a lot of time in spark, may be when doing overwrite, it need to spend a lot of time in io or in something else.

I also compare the executing time between insert overwrite statement and insert into statement.

**1. insert overwrite statement and insert into statement in spark:**

***insert overwrite statement costs about 10 minutes***

***insert into statement costs about 30 seconds***

**2. insert into statement in spark and insert into statement in hive-client:**

***spark costs about 30 seconds***

***hive-client costs about 20 seconds***

the difference is so little that we can ignore

Comment: [Related Spark JIRA task](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18107)